# I have this code to send mail from java showing error

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

```
      package Controller;

      import java.util.Properties;
      import javax.mail.*;
      import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
      import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

     public class SendMail {
      static String from = "******@gmail.com";
     static String pass ="*****";
     static String to = "****@gmail.com";
     static String host = "smtp.gmail.com";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();
          properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
          properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
          properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
          properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
          properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

          try{
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);


      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));


      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                               new InternetAddress(to));


      message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");


      message.setText("Ithis is a test");


      Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
      transport.connect(host, from, pass);
      transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
      transport.close();
      System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
   }

      catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();


      }
        }
    }
```

This code shows the error of:
        javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
Could anyone help me, why can't it convert socket to TLS. What can I do to resolve the error?? Please do help.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has a pointer to some [SSL debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#ssldebug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Gmail does not allow "less-secure" Apps to access your email.

In order to get your code to run:

- Sign into your gmail account in a browser.
- Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
- Set the **Access for less secure apps** option to **Turn on**

Answer (score 0):

Either the certificate has not been installed in file `cacerts` or you might want to set the google smtp url as "trusted". try add this code

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

on the other note. You might need to set the `javax.mail.Authenticator` when you try to get the `session`

Answer (score 0):

// Build session to create MimeMessage to send

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("name_here", "password_here");
            }
        });
```

Comment: **DO NOT** [set any socket factory properties](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).